# In UML, how do you call the object for which you build a state diagram?

Tags: uml

State diagrams in UML are always constructed for a specific class (that is, to describe the behavior of instances of that class). Thus, every state diagram is associated to a specific object for which it defines its behavior. What is the name of this object? the closest I could find in the UML standard is the term 'context object', as in here (section 14.2.3.1 in UML v2.5.1):

> The event pool for a StateMachine execution belongs to either its context Classifier object or ...

But I could not find anyone that uses this term.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. You seem to be asking several: how do you call an object, what is the name of an object, and, implicitly, what is a "context classifier", and what is a "context Classifier object".

Comment: I am asking what is the name given to the object for which we build the state machine.

Comment: What is the name of a class instance? That’s the name given to the object. Object and instance are the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

I use an answer to not have to cut the following in several comments.

> State diagrams in UML are always constructed for a specific class

You have to speak about *state machine*, not about *diagram*, and in your case visibly you speak about *behavior state machine* (not about *protocol state machine*).

A diagram is just a *picture* showing a part of the model.

> Thus, every state diagram is associated to a specific object for which it defines its behavior. What is the name of the object?

That depends, if your state machine defines the behavior of an operation then your *object* is that operation and its name is the name of the operation.

> that is, to describe the behavior of *instances of that class*

*If I well understand* this is from where your error comes from. You are focused on instances of class, but a state machine does not define the behavior of instances of a class, so to try to know the 'name' of theses instance as no sense.

Comment: But if I describe an operation does this operation float in space or is it an operation of some object? See in "Object Oriented Software Engineering using UML, Patterns and Java" (page 96): "A UML state machine is a notation for describing the sequence of states an object goes through in response to external events ... A state is a condition satisfied by the attributes of an object".

Comment: @DavidFaitelson I only refer to the norm, and in UML an operation is not floating in space but a BehaviorialFeature of an Interface, DataType, or Class. Anyway, what is your **real** problem ? I think the initial question is already the attempt of a solution

Comment: The last paragraph is false. A state machine typically does govern behavior of every instance of a class. Each instance separately receives signals and operation calls with an implicit “this” argument, which causes transitions between states for that instance.

Comment: @JimL. I speak about the _definition_ of the state machine, not about its _execution(s)_. Its definition is the same for all the instances

Comment: @bruno: you said, "a state machine does not define the behavior of instances of a class". A state machine is defined at the class level to define how every particular instance will respond to a particular signal / operation in its current state.

Comment: @JimL. please do not extract sentence from their context to modify their meaning. Also note that in case the state machine represents the behavior of an operation defined for the class rather than its instances (so declared _static_ in C++/Java, _@staticmethod_ in Python etc) that state machine does not _define how every particular instance will respond_ ;-)

Comment: @JimL. your first comment comes close to what I am looking for. You said "Each instance receives ... with an implicit "this" argument" --- this "this" is the object whose behavior the state machine describes. But saying this sentence is terribly cumbersome. From the quote in your answer "The receiving object becomes the context object for the execution" would you agree that "the context object" is better than "the object whose behavior the state machine describes"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone who has worked on the still-unadopted Precise Semantics for State Machines specification at the OMG will correct me if I’m wrong, but I believe there are three possible execution contexts.

The first is that of an “active class”, where each instance runs in its own thread and you send signals to it. The second is that of a normal class, where you call operations on or send signals to a normal instance, in the usual way. The third is that of a BehavioredClassifier, where each instance starts a special classifierBehavior as soon as it is created.

§13.2.3.5 of the UML 2.5 spec says:

> The receiving object becomes the context object for the execution of
>   any invoked methods.
>
> NOTE. Methods of a Reception are always invoked asynchronously, while
>   the methods of an Operation may be invoked either synchronously or
>   asynchronously, depending on how the Operation is called.

A state machine is defined for one of those execution contexts to determine how an instance will respond to a particular event, given its current state.

Yes, every state machine (possibly depicted in a diagram) is associated with an object, but it is not some *specific* object with some *special* name. Rather, a state machine governs how *every* instance of a particular class will respond to events, given its current state. And the name of an instance is whatever variable happens to hold a reference to it.

Comment: Warning as I already said answering to your remark in may answer an operation can be defined for the class itself rather than for its instances. "_And the name of an instance is whatever variable happens to hold a reference to it_" that sentence is problematic because several variables having different names can hold a reference to a given instance (=> several names) or none directly (=> no name) or even none indirectly in case of memory leak. An instance is a _PackageableElement_ so a _NamedElement_, useless to search a name elsewhere